# How do you create a Windows 10 Enterprise App Store?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10-preview, windows-store

In Windows 10 it is possible to create a [Windows 10 Enterprise Store](http://blogs.windows.com/business/2014/11/20/windows-10-a-store-thats-ready-for-business/), though I'm not really sure how to do so. I can't find any guidance online, and I'm not even sure the terms to search for.

I have multiple laptops available to use if it isn't possible by just using multiple Hyper-V virtual machines on my desktop. I'm not really sure where to start since I don't have any administrator experience.

Comment: wait when Windows 10 is out on 29th July/August 1st for Enterprise users. I think Microsoft will publish a lot of details at this dates.

Comment: @magicandre1981 they didn't :D

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt ask it in their technet forums

Comment: An overview of how the private Business Store works and how to get started is available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn986864(v=VS.85).aspx It is likely someone with an Azure AD domain can try the procedure and create a nice answer to this.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3338 May also be useful

Answer (score 5):

When available, organizations will be able to create own private sections of the existing Windows Store. Authentication to access said private store will be enabled via Azure Active Directory and will house the organization's custom apps. Apps can be assigned to users via IT admins and/or users are provided access to the organization's private section of the Store allowing the to download pre-approved apps.

Further details regarding this can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/whats-new/windows-store-for-business-overview

As there is no publicly available timeline as to when the Windows 10 Enterprise store, organizations can currently utilize Intune/System Center to enable Company Portal which can also create a private app repository outside to the Windows Store instance. Further details regarding this solution can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/02/11/step-by-step-enabling-mobile-application-distribution-via-windows-intune.aspx

Comment: The Windows Business store is not currently available and timelines for its availability have not been publicly shared.  The Company Portal solution mentioned is the suggested alternative should need for Windows Business store be immediate.

Comment: Are you saying that the answer to the question is: "You can't currently do this."? That might very well be the answer, but it would be nice to have something definitive saying so. In http://windowsitpro.com/windows-10/microsoft-opening-windows-store-businesses for example they mention "in the coming months." and no official launch seems to have taken place.

Comment: Understood.  Used your suggestion to modify the original answer as prescribed.  I will also follow up when the availability to the Windows Business store becomes public.

Comment: @AnthonyBartolo: It's not nice to undervote my answer, and without even leaving an explanation. It's much better to let the poster and the community decide on the best answer or answers - don't start flame wars on this forum.

Comment: @harrymc: I just checked my records to confirm.  I did not down vote your answer (or anyone else's answer). My intention here is to help. I have no interest in causing any conflicts I assure you.

Comment: @harrymc: Odd.  My reputation lists -2 at 20:04 but my all actions show no downvotes and my votes only show 4 upvotes.  Again I assure you I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: My apologies, this is then a coincidence of downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

A long Microsoft video explaining the Business Store can be found here :
[Using the Business Store Portal with Windows 10 Devices](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3338),
where a demonstration is also given of the portal and its capabilities;
and see also the article
[Whatever happened to Microsoft's Windows Update for Business?](http://www.zdnet.com/article/whatever-happened-to-microsofts-windows-update-for-business/).

When available, the store will probably be accessed via https://businessstore.microsoft.com.
At the moment, this website is asking for a login that I don't have.
You are supposed to be able to ask for a login by emailing `businessstore@microsoft.com` (but you might not yet get an answer).

[image: Business Store image1]

[image: Business Store image2]

[image: Business Store image3]